# Is it possible to nest one (or more) layout(s) within another, different layout(s) in d3?

Tags: javascript, layout, d3.js

I'm trying to build a force-directed layout, wherein the connected nodes have their own internal layout that is not simply a recursive force-directed layout (which, I believe, would be possible with the hierarchy layout). The "inner" layout would be custom, but, for illustration let's say I wanted the nodes, internally, to have a partition layout. Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried for now? Did you attempt to just add this layout as a node?

Comment: @ChrisJamesC: I have not tried anything, yet. I'm not sure how you would even add a layout as a node. Would I do my top-level selectAll().enter().append()… and then do a selectAll().enter().append() on the nodes I'd just created? That part makes enough sense to me I could poke around, but the layout engine seems more prescriptive about hierarchies like this.

Comment: @Lars: That's not exactly helpful.

Comment: @thomasqbrady: Indeed, but that's all you're asking. In principle, you can do this. You could have groups of elements for each force layout "node". But unless you provide more concrete information (How is this internal layout built? Do you want to display using SVG, HTML canvas...?) we can't really help you.

Comment: @Lars My question is about using layouts. You can automatically lay out a set of nodes in a force-directed graph with D3 without having to write the force-directed graph logic yourself. And you can can recursively layout out a force-directed graph inside a force-directed graph with the hierarchy layout, but how could you use two of d3's layout nested (a tree within a force-directed layout, or similar)?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, the two layouts could be independent. That is, you have a set of SVG `g` elements that you layout using the top layout and within each of the `g`s you apply the other layout. In this case you can apply them totally independently.

Answer (score 1):

My question was really twofold:

1. can you pull off having more than one style of layout (for instance, a bubble graph *inside* a force-directed graph) in a sensible way with D3, or is D3 the wrong tool for such a thing, and
2. Can you use D3 layouts for each of these layouts, or do you have to do everything custom.

In the end, the design changed, and no longer called for this odd scenario. Being much more familiar with D3, though, I think I can answer.

Yes. It can be done. Each layout is its own discrete object, with its own data on which to work, and can be given its own DOM elements to populate. Creating two layouts that even shared the same data and DOM outputs would probably work, if you could manage the interaction between the two (making sure one only overrode changes from the other when desired).

What I know you *can* do for sure is manually manipulate *anything* that D3 is doing. At one point during development, actually, I did have two layouts on the same page, come to think of it. I was laying out half the graph with pre-determined x/y coordinates, and allowing the rest to be laid out by the force directed layout. That first set, the manually placed nodes, could have been placed by some other logic than pre-determined coordinates, and the functionality would have been roughly the same.